# Handling camera and user rotation

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-orientation

I've been going through a lot of answers, but there is so much code that I don't know which direction to choose. I hope somebody can point me in the right direction.

I have custom Camera application where I display the preview from front or back camera (`SurfaceHolder`). I have a button where users can rotate the preview image for 90/180/270 degrees. That value is saved and applied to the camera and preview image.

However the orientation of the image that comes out when users take the picture is not same. My question is: how can I account for user and device orientation so that the output image is rotated the same as the preview image?

Answer (score 0):

One possible direction (if you are on Android Studio) would be to pull the code from [GitHub here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/AndyCam), step through it and modify it to your needs. It certainly does not do 'whatever your app does', but it can get you off-the-ground (or may confuse you even more). AND WATCH OUT, IT HANDLES ONLY THE REAR CAM. Anyway, a little bit of info up front.

1/ When your activity starts (onCreate), record its rotation and lock it so the view does not jump around anytime you re-position your phone. Your orientation may be PORT or LAND based on your initial state. You may also 'force it' to for instance LAND, but it will look jerky when your activity starts.

2/ onSurfaceChanged gives you your surface size. It can be PORT (W < H) or LAND (W > H). You send your surface W,H to the camera manager to select the ideal preview size. Since the 'getSupportedPreviewSizes' are mostly (I would like to say always, but not 100% sure) of type LAND (W > H), you have swap your surface W and H accordingly.

3/ Don't forget to 'setDisplayOrientation' to your initial orientation so your preview is not sideways.

4/ almost certainly, your surface W:H is not exactly the same as one of the offered preview sizes W:H, resulting in squashed / stretched preview (just look at any round object with you cam preview). So now you have to adjust you surface size again, see 'setLayoutParams' at the end of 'surfaceChanged'. It's woth noticing, that you may adjust you surface either to FIT-IN (letterbox), resulting in two background colored stripes on sides, or FILL (pan&scan) filling your full surface area with some of the overflowing your screen (who cares).

This helps you to get the preview right. I should also mention that there's another quirk with the preview orientation. Some tablets (Nexus 1Gen,...) have natural orientation LAND, but some (like SAMSUNG 8 3.0) have it PORT. This issue is adjusted during initialization and expresses itself in the 'isLandTab' boolean.

5/ Now, when you finally get your picture from Camera.getPicture, you just have to rotate it back using the same amount as you rotated your preview. Rather costly operation (memory-wise). You have to decompress it to a bitmap, rotate and .... do whatever you wanted to do. Compress again, display, ....

Now, when you finally got through this nonsensical rant, you may ask yourself. Isn't it better just to force the activity into LAND, lock it. In this case you

1. Don't have to swap he surface W,H
2. Don't have to setDisplayOrientation
3. don't have to rotate the picture after you get it.

You still have to do the dance with adjusting the the surface view size to fit the ratio of the offered / selected preview.

Have fun, Good Luck